# In Before Trigger update would like to revert the entered values in Task except whoid

Tags: before-trigger

Requirement: After Task record is created then any update should not happen except contacts change (WhoID). I have written simple code in Before Update Trigger but enable to get the right syntax for copying the changed value from Old Trigger to new Trigger field in if-condition (commented out), (or) how do we get dynamic field Name so that we assign the old value, any help would be greatly appreciated:

```
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult objSchema = task.sObjectType.getDescribe();
  Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = objSchema.fields.getMap();

  for (Task Tsk: Trigger.new) {
        Task oldTask = Trigger.oldMap.get(Tsk.ID);
        for (String fieldName : fieldMap.keySet()){
            if ((Tsk.get(fieldName) != OldTask.get(fieldName)) && !fieldName.equalsIgnoreCase('WhoId')){
                //Tsk.fieldName = OldTask.get(fieldName);
            }
      }     
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The complement to `get` in this case is `put`.

```
record.put(field, oldRecord.get(field));
```

Be careful to not try to set fields which are not updateable:

```
Set<String> updateableFields = new Set<String>();
for (SObjectField field : SObjectType.Task.fields.getMap().values())
{
    if (field.getDescribe().isUpdateable())
    {
        updateableFields.add(String.valueOf(field));
    }
}
```

Generate this list before looping through records individually. Then loop through this field collection instead of the one you are currently using.

Comment: You should add a comment about filtering out read-only fields to prevent runtime exceptions...

Answer (score 0):

In continuation of `@Adrain Larson` post, 
I used below to revert all the changes that user entered except `WhoId`:

```
for (Task newTask: Trigger.new) {
   Task oldTask = Trigger.oldMap.get(newTask.ID);
   for(String fieldName : updateableFields){
       if(newTask.get(fieldName) != oldTask.get(fieldName)){
          newTask.put(fieldName, oldTask.get(fieldName));
       }
   }
}
```